# KSOAP and web server communication (PropertyInfo)

Tags: android, weblogic, ksoap, propertyinfo

So I'm developing an Android app that should connect to a web service. This connection is working fine. I've tested it using a simple method that returns "Hello Christian". This is displayed correct in the app. If I try to do this with a parameter (name) it returns "Hello null".

Technically I'm working with Android 4.2.2 and KSOAP 2.6.5. The web service is running on an Oracle WebLogic v12. Following my source code:

```
private final String NAMESPACE_Local = "http://test.com/";
private final String URL_Local = "http://168.185.226.69:7001/neuesProjekt/neuerWebServiceService";
private final String SOAP_ACTION_Local = "Hello_Action_Name";
    private final String METHOD_NAME_Local = "helloname";

    private final String URL_Local = "http://168.185.226.21:7001/myTest/myTestWebServiceService";
  private final String SOAP_ACTION_Local = "Hello_Action_Extend";
   private final String METHOD_NAME_Local = "hello_extend";

        public void LocalServer(View view)
        {
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.update_text);

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_Local, METHOD_NAME_Local);
    //      request.addProperty("name", "Christian");

    //      String name = "Christian";
    //      
    //      PropertyInfo nameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    //        nameProp.name = "name";
    //        nameProp.type = String.class;
    //        nameProp.namespace = NAMESPACE_Local;
    //        nameProp.setValue(name);
    //        request.addProperty(nameProp);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_Local);

            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_Local, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                Log.i("myApp", response.toString());


            text.setText(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Device or service offline",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I've tried to add the propertyInfo in two ways. First with the simple request.addProperty and the long way creating the PropertyInfo and adding it afterwards. Both ways don't work.
However when I try it with a server from some tutorial (eg. celsius to fahrenheit) it works and returns the proper answer.

Here the 'code' from the web server:

```
package com.test;

import javax.jws.*;

@WebService
public class myTestWebService {

    @WebMethod(action="Hello_Action")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @WebMethod(action="Hello_Action_Extend")
    public String hello_extend(String name)
    {
        return "hello "+name;
    }
}
```

Following the WSDL file in case it helps solve my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.6hudson-86  svn-revision#12773. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://test.com/" name="myTestWebServiceService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:tns="http://test.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://test.com/" schemaLocation="myTestWebServiceService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="hello">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/>
  </message>
  <message name="helloResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="myTestWebService">
    <operation name="hello">
      <input wsam:Action="Hello_Action" message="tns:hello"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://test.com/myTestWebService/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="myTestWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:myTestWebService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="hello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="Hello_Action"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="myTestWebServiceService">
    <port name="myTestWebServicePort" binding="tns:myTestWebServicePortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

So I hope one of you can help me because I'm quite clueless what to do.
Kind regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great at this and in fact have only this week got my web services to work.

Try

```
envelope.dotNet = true;
String name = "Christian";
request.addProperty("name", name);
```

Or

```
envelope.dotNet = true;
PropertyInfo nameProp =new PropertyInfo();
nameProp.setName("name");
nameProp.setType(String.class);
nameProp.setValue(name);
request.addProperty(nameProp);
```

I hope this solves it for you